# having trouble with the README Generator but for some reason fs.writeToFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, writefile

This is the code that is causing the error:

```js
const writeToFile = data  => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile('./dist/generated-README.md', data, err => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            resolve({
                ok: true,
                message: console.log('File created!')
            });
        })
    })
}
```

I'm getting an error that says that `fs.writeToFile` is not a function. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeToFile` is not a function because it's called `fs.writeFile`. You would need to simply change the name. Also, I'm not sure about that `console.Console.log` function, It's just `console.log`.

```js
const writeToFile = data  => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile('./dist/generated-README.md', data, err => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            resolve({
                ok: true,
                message: console.log('File created!')
            });
        })
    })
}
```